# Finding out the code coverage percent for new code alone using sonar/jacoco

Tags: java, sonarqube, jacoco

We have a new mandate in our team that any new that is pushed to any of our GIT repositories need to have 100% code coverage. We already have (actively used and not legacy, deprecatable) code in the repository for which the coverage is around 75-80% (based on the repository).

We are generating sonar reports with jacoco being the underlying coverage analysis tool.

However, when we see the reports, we are not able to identify the coverage % for the new code alone. Is there a way to do that?

Please note that exclusion of modules or files is not always feasible since some of the code that is added is in an existing class.

Is there some setting that forces sonar/jacoco to provide this information?

Comment: A sidenote: 100% code coverage is probably not a wise requirement. This will often force you to do meaningless tests just to get that last percent.

Comment: Agree @Keppil. To outline the process: if a dev is not able to achieve 100%, he needs to provide the validation to the leads. This ensures that they try to push it as high as possible. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how your reports need to look like, but maybe the "differentials" help:

http://www.sonarqube.org/differentials-four-ways-to-see-whats-changed/